# Compress Xamarin Android APK assemblies

Tags: xamarin.android, compression, apk, assemblies

Is it possible to compress Xamarin assemblies into assemblies.blob after decompressing them using decompress-assemblies command line tool included in xamarin-android?

Comment: According to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/11/11.0#smaller-app-package-sizes), the assemblies will be compressed into the apk default. And the apk file contents into assemblies.blob.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I need to recompress them again after modifying a DLL.

Comment: But the assemblies has been compressed into the apk before you modifying a DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got familiar with the structure of assemblies.blob file from https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/main/Documentation/project-docs/AssemblyStores.md and used the following to be able to modify a DLL inside that store file:

1. Decompress the file using [`decompress-assemblies`](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/tree/main/tools/decompress-assemblies) utility
2. Patch the DLL file needed
3. Read the descriptor index for the compressed DLL, to get that, use [`assembly-store-reader`](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/tree/main/tools/assembly-store-reader), then write down the offset of the assembly that requires patching, open assemblies.blob in a hex editor, navigate to the offset of the DLL, descriptor index will be inside the uint after the compression magic uint (XALZ)
   [image: Descriptor index in that example is 29.]
4. Compress the DLL file again using [`AssemblyCompression`](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/681887ebdbd192ce7ce1cd02221d4939599ba762/src/Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks/Utilities/AssemblyCompression.cs) class:  and use the descriptor index as an input to `AssemblyData` constructor
5. Add this method to [`AssemblyStoreReader`](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/c92702619f5fabcff0ed88e09160baf9edd70f41/tools/assembly-store-reader/AssemblyStoreReader.cs) to recreate the assemblies.blob with the patched DLL:

   ```
   internal void SaveStoreToStream(Stream output)
   {
       EnsureStoreDataAvailable();

       // Load patched DLL.
       MemoryStream dllStream;
       using (var fs = File.Open("/location/of/patched.dll.lz4", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
       {
           dllStream = new MemoryStream();
           fs.CopyTo(dllStream);
       }

       // Index of the assembly to patch in assemblies.blob file.
       var patchedAssemblyIndex = 17;
       uint offsetDiff = (uint)(Assemblies[patchedAssemblyIndex].DataSize - dllStream.Length);


       using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(output))
       {
           bw.Write(ASSEMBLY_STORE_MAGIC);
           bw.Write(ASSEMBLY_STORE_FORMAT_VERSION);
           bw.Write(LocalEntryCount);
           bw.Write(GlobalEntryCount);
           bw.Write(StoreID);

           foreach (AssemblyStoreAssembly assembly in Assemblies)
           {
               if (assembly.RuntimeIndex > patchedAssemblyIndex)
               {
                   bw.Write(assembly.DataOffset - offsetDiff);
               } else
               {
                   bw.Write(assembly.DataOffset);
               }

               if (assembly.RuntimeIndex == patchedAssemblyIndex)
               {
                   bw.Write((uint)dllStream.Length);
               } else
               {
                   bw.Write(assembly.DataSize);
               }

               bw.Write(assembly.DebugDataOffset);
               bw.Write(assembly.DebugDataSize);
               bw.Write(assembly.ConfigDataOffset);
               bw.Write(assembly.ConfigDataSize);
           }

           foreach (AssemblyStoreHashEntry entry in GlobalIndex32)
           {
               bw.Write(entry.Hash);
               bw.Write(entry.MappingIndex);
               bw.Write(entry.LocalStoreIndex);
               bw.Write(entry.StoreID);
           }

           foreach (AssemblyStoreHashEntry entry in GlobalIndex64)
           {
               bw.Write(entry.Hash);
               bw.Write(entry.MappingIndex);
               bw.Write(entry.LocalStoreIndex);
               bw.Write(entry.StoreID);
           }

           foreach (AssemblyStoreAssembly assembly in Assemblies) {
               if (assembly.RuntimeIndex == patchedAssemblyIndex)
               {
                   bw.Write(dllStream.ToArray());
               }
               else
               {
                   using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                   {
                       assembly.ExtractImage(stream);
                       bw.Write(stream.ToArray());
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. Write the stream passed to the above method to a new file and that will be the assemblies.blob with the patched DLL
7. Use apktool to recreate the APK, align and sign, then it should be working with your patched DLL

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and took a long time to find a proper solution.
The best solution I could find is in [this GitHub project](https://github.com/jakev/pyxamstore).

After ZL4 compress algorithm things changed and most solutions were deprecated. For more detail, please check [here](https://www.thecobraden.com/posts/unpacking_xamarin_assembly_stores/).

After applying the steps on the above Github link, I could obtain the DLLs and finally decompile them with `dotPeek` or another app.